# Should errno/perror methodology be used today to detect errors?

Tags: c, error-handling

I know many questions have been asked previously about error handling in C but this is specifically about errno stuff.

I want to ask whether we should use the errno/perror functionality to handle errors gracefully at runtime.I am asking this because MSVC uses it and Win32 api also uses it heavily.I don't know anything about gcc or 'linux api'.Today both gcc and MSVC say that errno/perror can be used safely in a multithreaded environment.So what's your view?

thanks.

Comment: Are you going to keep asking this question until you get an answer you like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using errno with user defined error codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438133/using-errno-with-user-defined-error-codes)

Comment: @David:No it's over,satisfied with sarnold's answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that using `errno` *alone* is a **bad idea**: standard library functions invoke other standard library functions to do their work. If one of the called functions fails, `errno` will be set to indicate the cause of the error, and the library function *might still succeed*, if it has been programmed in a manner that it can fall back to other mechanisms.

Consider `malloc(3)` -- it might be programmed to try `mmap(.., MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS)` as a first attempt, and *if that fails* fall back to `sbrk(2)` to allocate memory. Or consider `execvp(3)` -- it may probe a dozen directories when attempting to execute a program, and many of them might fail first. The 'local failure' doesn't mean a larger failure. And the function *you* called won't set `errno` back to `0` before returning to you -- it might have a legitimate but irrelevant value left over from earlier.

You cannot simply check the value of `errno` to see if you have encountered an error. `errno` *only* makes sense if the standard library function involved *also returned an error return*. (Such as `NULL` from `getcwd(3)` or `-1` from `read(2)`, or "a negative value" from `printf(3)`.)

But in the cases when standard library functions do fail, `errno` is the only way to discover *why* they failed. When other library functions (not supplied by the standard libraries) fail, they might use `errno` or they might provide similar but different tools (see e.g. `ERR_print_errors(3ssl)` or `gai_strerror(3)`.) You'll have to check the documentation of the libraries you're using for full details.

Comment: then what is the alternative to detect **error** in _standard library functions_ & _internal standard library function_... BTW thanks for ur post, it was very helpful

Comment: @CAD_coding, sadly there's no _easy_ way around checking the standard library functions for errors the hard way -- read the manpage for every function you use, look in the `RETURN VALUE` section to discover what the error returns are (sometimes `0`, sometimes `-1`, sometimes `NULL`), and write code to check for the errors. Only in the case of an error return will `errno` have a _meaning_.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is really a question of "should" but if you are programming in C and using the low level C/posix API, there really is no other option.  Of course you can wrap it up if this offends your stylistic sensibilities, but under the hood that is how it has to work (at least as long as POSIX is a standard).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, errno is safe to read/write in multiple thread or process, but not with perror(). It's a standard library that not re-entrant.